# Boost Module: Delete Cache for single node on update

Tags: commerce, caching

I use Boost module for Drupal Commerce.
How can i clear the cache for only one cached node after updating that node.
I don´t want to clear the cache for all nodes but only for the one i updating.

Comment: Would be very much like to see an answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using the Cache Expiration module: 
https://www.drupal.org/project/expire

You might use the rules integration:

- event: a node is saved
- condition: (type of node, etc - depends on your scenario, might be nothing)
- action: expire URL

Comment: I can´t find the Action "expire URL" but only "clear a specific cache cid" or "clear urls from the page cache". Which action do i have to chose and which parameters need to be configured to specify the updated node?